# How do you mock scala call-by name in Mockito

Tags: scala, unit-testing, mockito, scala-java-interop

Im trying to mock scala call-by name method in mockito. But running into this error.

> This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
>       //incorrect:
>       someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String"); When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers. For example:
>       //correct:
>       someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));

Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks!

Here is the sample code and test file: Here Im trying to mock ***createCommand*** function. and give a mock so I can verify that ***execute*** is called or not.

```
  package com.example

  class Command(key: String, func: => Long) {
    def execute(): Long = {
      println("Command.execute")
      println("key = " + key)
      println("func = " + func)
      func
    }

  }

  class CacheHelper {


    def createCommand(cacheKey: String, func: => Long): Command = {
      println("cacheKey = " + cacheKey)
      println("func = " + func)
      new Command(cacheKey, func)
      //    Mock this method
    }

    def getOrElse(cacheKey: String)(func: => Long): Long = {

      println("circuitBreakerEnabled = " + isCircuitBreakerEnabled)
      if (isCircuitBreakerEnabled) {
        val createCommand1: Command = createCommand(cacheKey, func)
        println("createCommand1 = " + createCommand1)
        createCommand1.execute()
      }
      else {
        util.Random.nextInt()
      }
    }

    def isCircuitBreakerEnabled: Boolean = {
      println("CacheHelper.isCircuitBreakerEnabled")
      false
    }
  }

  import com.example.{CacheHelper, Command}
  import org.mockito.Matchers._
  import org.mockito.Mockito._
  import org.scalatest.{Matchers, _}
  import org.scalatest.mock.MockitoSugar

  class ExampleSpec extends FlatSpec with Matchers with BeforeAndAfter with MockitoSugar {

    "it" should "call commands execute" in {
      val cacheHelper: CacheHelper = new CacheHelper
      val commandMock: Command = mock[Command]
      val spyCacheHelper = spy(cacheHelper)

      when(spyCacheHelper.isCircuitBreakerEnabled).thenReturn(true)
      when(spyCacheHelper.createCommand(any(), anyLong())).thenReturn(commandMock)

      val result: Long = spyCacheHelper.getOrElse("key")(1L)
      println("result = " + result)
      verify(commandMock).execute()

    }

  }
```

Comment: You'll need to include more of the error stack trace for someone to help you answer this question.

Comment: you've send a value as parameter `anyLong()` but instead you have to send some function from `Unit => Long`

Comment: Im getting the error with `Unit=>Long` since this is call-by name params, not functional arg.

Comment: Here are the dependencies if some one wants give it a try: `libraryDependencies += "org.mockito" % "mockito-all" % "1.10.19" % "test"
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.4" % "test"`

Comment: keep an on this one:  https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/1134

Answer (score 3):

Can't do it with Mockito: [Verifying by-name parameters in Mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24323213/verifying-by-name-parameters-in-mockito)

Should be able to do it with scalamock:
[How to mock a call-by-name argument (like getOrElse) using ScalaMock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18294830/how-to-mock-a-call-by-name-argument-like-getorelse-using-scalamock)

Answer (score 2):

You can use https://github.com/mockito/mockito-scala

```
import com.example.{CacheHelper, Command}
import org.mockito.ArgumentMatchersSugar._
import org.mockito.IdiomaticMockito
import org.scalatest.{Matchers, _}

  class ExampleSpec extends FlatSpec with Matchers with BeforeAndAfter with IdiomaticMockito {

    "it" should "call commands execute" in {
      val cacheHelper: CacheHelper = new CacheHelper
      val commandMock: Command = mock[Command]
      val spyCacheHelper = spy(cacheHelper)

      spyCacheHelper.isCircuitBreakerEnabled shouldReturn true
      spyCacheHelper.createCommand(any[String], any[Long]) shouldReturn commandMock 

      val result: Long = spyCacheHelper.getOrElse("key")(1L)
      println("result = " + result)
      verify(commandMock).execute()

    }

  }
```